# Passing event and props from child to parent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've started splitting some code into `presentational/container` components and  I'd like to call a function in the `child/presentational` component and pass both the event and some sort of prop back to the parent.

Parent:

```
class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
        this.reroll = this.reroll.bind(this);
    }

    test(key, e){
        console.log(key, e)
    }
    render() {
        return <Child test={()=>this.test} />
    }
}
```

Child:

```
var Child = () => {
    return ( 
        <select onChange={props.test('test-key')}>
            <option value='1'> Option 1 </option>
            //etc...
        </select>
    )
}
```

Normally, when I had my code all in one place I would write the onChange function like this.

```
<select onChange={props.test.bind(this, 'test-key')}>
```

But binding this in the child causes it to no longer function. No other props passed to this function get returned to the parent. Is there any way that I can write this such that I can get back 'test-key'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put function call inside callback of `onChange` event.

```
 <select onChange={()=>props.test('test-key')}>
```

In this way you can also pass `event` object too.

```
 <select onChange={(event)=>props.test(event,'test-key')}>
```

Answer (score 12):

First: You should avoid binding the functions as much as possible in the render as it causes a new function to be created each time render is called. You could easily avoid it in your case like

define the test function using arrow function

```
test(key, e){
    console.log(key, e)
}
```

and then use it in the parent like

```
<Child test={this.test} />
```

now in the child component

```
test = (e) => {
   this.props.test('test-key', e)
}

<select onChange={this.test}>
```

Answer (score 6):

Anyone coming here trying to find same thing for functional component. I have an example here.
Parent component example:

```
<SaveButton
 newsArticleId="someId"
 onClickCallback={handleSaveNote}
    />

const handleSaveNote = (e, articleId) => {    
const event = e || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();     
  setArticleId(articleId);
  ....code removed
 };
```

Child component example:

```
 const SaveButton = ({ newsArticleId, onClickCallback }) => {
 return (
  <button
   id={newsArticleId}
   className='btn btn-sm btn-primary'
   type='button'
   data-toggle='dropdown'
   aria-haspopup='true'
   aria-expanded='false'
   onClick={(e) => onClickCallback(e, newsArticleId)}
  >
   Save
  </button>
 );
};
```